# How to find unique array within an array of arrays?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, processing

I'm trying to check whether an array of arrays has any duplicate values. The end goal would be an if statement saying:

if (arr does NOT have duplicate values) {continue code}

```
int [][] arr = new int[3][2];
int [] x = new int[1];
arr[0][0] = 1;
arr[0][1] = 1;
arr[1][0] = 1;
arr[1][1] = 2;
arr[2][0] = 1;
arr[2][1] = 2;


x = arr.getUnique(); /I assume it'll use getUnique() but I can't even get that to work
```

Any help would be awesome! Thanks

Comment: You want compare every value in an array to make sure that none are there more than once, do I get this right?

Answer (score 0):

Java has a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) you can use to have a collection without duplicates.

Find a way to convert your array into a `HashSet` and compare the number of their elements. If they have the same number of elements, each element in your array is unique, if the HashSet is smaller, it means some duplicates have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a helper function of your own like this:

```
private static boolean arrayHasDuplicates(int[][] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < arr.length; y++)
            {
                if (arr[i].length != arr[y].length) continue;
                if (i == y) continue;
                boolean same = true;
                
                for (int x = 0; x < arr[y].length; x++)
                {
                    if (arr[i][x] != arr[y][x]) {
                        same = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (same) return same;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```